# Python asyncio how to give priority to one function during concurrent execution of its subfunctions

Tags: python, async-await, concurrency, python-asyncio

Here is a schematic version of my current setup:

```
import asyncio

async def child(args):
    # await some things

async def parent(args):
    # await some other things
    if some_condition:
        await asyncio.gather(child(args1), child(args2))

async def main():
    await asyncio.gather(parent(args3), parent(args4))

asyncio.run(main())
```

So in essence I'm running the `parent` function for different inputs concurrently. Every now and then some condition is met and as a result the corresponding `parent` process starts the concurrent execution of the `child` function for different inputs. Since the `child` function contains an `await`, it gives up control to the event loop such that other functions within this event loop can run.

My problem is that I only want the `child` processes to give up control in favor of other `child` processes of the same `parent` process (i.e. essentially blocking the other `parent` processes from running). However, in practice this is not the case and other `parent` processes are often running before the `child` processes are finished. This increases the time it takes for the `child` processes to complete (I actually have more than 2 `parent` processes, I'm just limiting it here for simplicity).

Is there a way to give priority to the `child` processes, such that they are completed as fast as possible? I tried a bunch of different `asyncio` methods but nothing seems to work. Maybe there's an easy way to run the code inside the if statement in a synchronous way, such that it blocks the event loop (while still running the `child` processes concurrently)?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You can use an `asyncio.Lock`. With a lock you can simulate a shared resource between coroutines, locking the access to a coroutine if already other owns the lock. In such way, can be implemented that one parent cannot invoke his childs if other parent is awaiting by the execution of his own childs.

```py
import asyncio
from time import time

# lock for parents when want to call childs
lock = asyncio.Lock()

async def child(parent, job):
    print(f"child of {parent} doing {job} at {time()}")
    await asyncio.sleep(3)

async def parent(name, jobs):
    print(f"parent {name} doing stuff")
    await asyncio.sleep(2)
    async with lock:    # only the childs of one parent will run concurrently
        await asyncio.gather(child(name, jobs[0]), child(name, jobs[1]))

async def main():
    await asyncio.gather(
        parent("parent1", ["job1", "job2"]),
        parent("parent2", ["job3", "job4"])
    )

asyncio.get_event_loop().run_until_complete(main())
```

Output:

```
parent parent1 doing stuff
parent parent2 doing stuff
child of parent1 doing job1 at 1650394577.7973263
child of parent1 doing job2 at 1650394577.7974186
child of parent2 doing job3 at 1650394580.801368
child of parent2 doing job4 at 1650394580.8014803
```

Note how the childs of `parent2` started to do his jobs 3 seconds after the childs of `parent1` ended.

**Without the lock** you get something like this, every child starts at the same time.

```
parent parent1 doing stuff
parent parent2 doing stuff
child of parent1 doing job1 at 1650395040.6458762
child of parent1 doing job2 at 1650395040.6460035
child of parent2 doing job3 at 1650395040.6460583
child of parent2 doing job4 at 1650395040.6460981
```

Hope this answer your quetion.

Comment: Hmm, this might be a step in the right direction but it's not yet entirely what I'm looking for. As you said, your solution blocks parents from running their children when another parent is already running its children. However, I want to take it a step further and block parents from doing _anything_ when another parent is already running its children. Do you think this is possible?

Comment: Two options. First, you can acquire the lock at the beginning of the parent, that will block all the other parents, beside you may not have your children running yet, in other words, a global lock for running a parent at a time. Second, check if the lock is free, in that case proceed to `# await some other things`, but what should be the behavoir if while you are awaiting that things the lock (that was free) is acquired by other parent?

Comment: The first option, I think that is not what you want. The second may be a problem, how useful is for you to know that the lock is free if after milisecond it may be acquired.